# Product form for common users in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, spree

I have a question about e-commerce offered by Spree in Ruby on Rails. I need to do an e-commerce where the users can create products to offer them to the public as well as that they can buy. Currently, Spree only allows you to add products to the administrator, but I also need common users can offer their products and also to link them with the user in the database.

There is a way to make a form that allows an common user to offer a product in Spree?, and if not, what other e-commerce would be easier to propose an e-commerce as I described. It is a project to do in a very short time and that is why I do it in RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, I would build a marketplace and allow users to register as *vendors*, so that they can offer their products (either free or paid).

You could look at the following gems to determine your needs:

- [SpreeMarketplace](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_marketplace)
- [SpreeDropShip](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship)

There is also non Rails options, like [WooCommerce for Wordpress](https://woocommerce.com/?utm_campaign=woocommerce%20branded&utm_source=adwords&utm_term=woocommerce&utm_content=28619674261&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpdnJBRC4ARIsAHC6k2LmWeIdaFiwkeqEpqc9G8A0wClZdEB_84ftmULI7eP8HIN_vR743xgaAuMVEALw_wcB) with a [MarketPlace extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/).

I hope this helps.